# request body is stringified incorrectly when doing POST from angular microfronted put in JSP

Tags: json, angular, jsp

So, I have this angular app acting as microfront, being put in JSP. When I access the angular app directly - on the site it is being hosted - everything works as intended. The issue happens when I try to use it at the JSP. POST data is constructed differently depending where a person is using the app

When I go directly to the app, POST body is constructed properly

```
the data
{
 yada: 123,
 foo: 'bar',
 array: [1, 2, 3]
}

request body
{
 "yada": 123,
 "foo": 'bar',
 "array": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

but when I access the app through JSP, it all goes bananas - the payload is

```
{
 "yada": 123,
 "foo": 'bar',
 "array": "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]
}
```

As you can see, the array is put in quotation marks, and every quotation inside is escaped, so of course the data cannot be properly consumed at the backend. This happens with all the arrays in payload

It's like the payload was stringified twice? Or is the issue related to page encoding?

http call in angular service:

```
 postData(data) {
return this.http.post(url, data)
// content type is set in nginx, which proxies the request further
```

unfortunately I do not have access to the JSP page source code, as it is in another IT sector